# Aptitude install error

Tags: apt, aptitude

I'm running `apt-get install aptitude` but it gives me this error:‌

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 aptitude : Depends: libcwidget3 but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.9) but 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04 is to be installed
            Depends: libxapian22 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

What is wrong ?

Here is some additional information:

```
$ uname -a
Linux ubuntu 3.19.0-47-generic #53~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jan 18 16:09:14 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ lsb_release -r
Release:    15.04

$ apt-cache policy aptitude libcwidget3 libstdc++6 libxapian22
 aptitude:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.6.11-1ubuntu3
  Version table:
     0.6.11-1ubuntu3 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/main amd64 Packages
     0.6.8.2-1ubuntu4 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libcwidget3:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.5.17-2ubuntu1
  Version table:
     0.5.17-2ubuntu1 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/main amd64 Packages
     0.5.16-3.5ubuntu1 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libstdc++6:
  Installed: 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04
  Candidate: 4.9.2-10ubuntu13
  Version table:
     4.9.2-10ubuntu13 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/main amd64 Packages
 *** 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libxapian22:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.2.19-1
  Version table:
     1.2.19-1 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/main amd64 Packages
     1.2.16-2ubuntu1 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

---

*Updates*

```
$ sudo apt-get install libstdc++6=4.9.2-10ubuntu13 :
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libstdc++6
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 18 not upgraded.
```

and

```
$ apt-cache policy libstdc++6
libstdc++6:
  Installed: 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04
  Candidate: 4.9.2-10ubuntu13
  Version table:
     4.9.2-10ubuntu13 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/main amd64 Packages
 *** 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

,

```
$ sudo dpkg -i libstdc++6_4.9.2-10ubuntu13_amd64.deb
(Reading database ... 103371 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack libstdc++6_4.9.2-10ubuntu13_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libstdc++6:amd64 (4.9.2-10ubuntu13) over (4.9.2-10ubuntu13) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libstdc++6:amd64:
 libstdc++6:amd64 depends on gcc-4.9-base (= 4.9.2-10ubuntu13); however:
  Version of gcc-4.9-base:amd64 on system is 4.9.3-0ubuntu4.

dpkg: error processing package libstdc++6:amd64 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libstdc++6:amd64
```

,

```
$ sudo apt-get install gcc-4.9-base=4.9.2-10ubuntu13
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gcc-4.9-base : Breaks: gcc-4.9-base:i386 (!= 4.9.2-10ubuntu13) but 4.9.3-0ubuntu4 is to be installed
 gcc-4.9-base:i386 : Breaks: gcc-4.9-base (!= 4.9.3-0ubuntu4) but 4.9.2-10ubuntu13 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

,

```
$ apt-cache policy gcc-4.9-base
gcc-4.9-base:
  Installed: 4.9.3-0ubuntu4
  Candidate: 4.9.3-0ubuntu4
  Version table:
 *** 4.9.3-0ubuntu4 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     4.9.2-10ubuntu13 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/main amd64 Packages
```

,

```
   $ sudo apt-get install gcc-4.9=4.9.2-10ubuntu13 gcc-4.9-base=4.9.2-10ubuntu13 gcc-4.9:i386=4.9.2-10ubuntu13 gcc-4.9-base:i386=4.9.2-10ubuntu13
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
    The following packages have unmet dependencies:
     gcc-4.9 : Depends: cpp-4.9 (= 4.9.2-10ubuntu13) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: libgcc-4.9-dev (= 4.9.2-10ubuntu13) but it is not going to be installed
               Conflicts: gcc-4.9:i386 but 4.9.2-10ubuntu13 is to be installed
     gcc-4.9:i386 : Depends: cpp-4.9:i386 (= 4.9.2-10ubuntu13) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: binutils:i386 (>= 2.25) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libgcc-4.9-dev:i386 (= 4.9.2-10ubuntu13) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libcloog-isl4:i386 (>= 0.17) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libgmp10:i386 (>= 2:5.0.1~) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libisl13:i386 (>= 0.10) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libmpc3:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libmpfr4:i386 (>= 3.1.2) but it is not going to be installed
                    Recommends: libc6-dev:i386 (>= 2.13-0ubuntu6) but it is not going to be installed
                    Conflicts: gcc-4.9 but 4.9.2-10ubuntu13 is to be installed
    E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35159/discussion-on-question-by-mohsen-parsaeian-aptitude-install-error).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is:

```
Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.9) but 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04 is to be installed
```

and the installation of the needed version fails

```
$ apt-get download libstdc++6
$ sudo dpkg -i libstdc++6_4.9.2-10ubuntu13_amd64.deb
...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libstdc++6:amd64:
 libstdc++6:amd64 depends on gcc-4.9-base (= 4.9.2-10ubuntu13); however:
  Version of gcc-4.9-base:amd64 on system is 4.9.3-0ubuntu4.
```

The output of `apt-cache policy gcc-4.9-base` says me, you have installed `gcc-4.9-base` with a DEB file or by a repository, which not longer exist in your system. For this reason:

1. Downgrade your `gcc-4.9` installation and as you have also installed the 32-bit packages, the same for the 32-bit packages.

   **But** the commands below are not helpful, for that reason we have to go the hard way, see point 2.

   ```
   sudo apt-get install gcc-4.9=4.9.2-10ubuntu13 gcc-4.9-base=4.9.2-10ubuntu13 gcc-4.9:i386=4.9.2-10ubuntu13 gcc-4.9-base:i386=4.9.2-10ubuntu13
   ```
2. The hard way

   ```
   mkdir ~/debs$$
   cd ~/debs$$
   wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-4.9/gcc-4.9-base_4.9.2-10ubuntu13_amd64.deb
   wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-4.9/gcc-4.9-base_4.9.2-10ubuntu13_i386.deb
   wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-4.9/gcc-4.9_4.9.2-10ubuntu13_amd64.deb
   wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-4.9/gcc-4.9_4.9.2-10ubuntu13_i386.deb
   sudo dpkg -i --force-all *.deb
   sudo apt-get install -f
   ```
3. Install `aptitude`

   ```
   sudo apt-get install aptitude
   ```

Comment: Add the output of `apt-cache policy gcc-4.9-base` to your question.

Comment: Have you used the command above? `sudo apt-get install gcc-4.9-base=4.9.2-10ubuntu13`

Comment: yes! result is the same.

Comment: Give me the error message

Comment: Added it to my question.

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: added output to my question!

Comment: I think must reinstall my server :-/

Comment: No. We can repair your system.

Comment: Run the commands in step 2

Comment: And give me the error messages here: http://paste.Ubuntu.com

Comment: When run apt-get download gcc-4.9 gcc-4.9:i386 gcc-4.9-base gcc-4.9-base:i386 shows me this : http://paste.ubuntu.com/14852479/

Comment: And when run sudo apt-cache search gcc-4.9-base shows me just this :gcc-4.9-base - GCC, the GNU Compiler Collection (base package)

Comment: Answer changed. Delete the DEB files first, before the new download.